# How to get default Japanese font without OS language set to Japanese

Tags: c#, fonts, localization

I have an application that sometimes has to display Japanese text even when the OS is set to English. This seems to magically work when a Japanese font is installed. But I want to programmatically make sure that a suitable font is installed so I can tell when the user will be seeing empty boxes.

It looks like `System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemfonts.defaultfont)) will give me the default when the OS is configured for Japanese, but of course I get the English default font when the OS is configured for English.

Is my only option to hard-code the names of all the fonts that Microsoft has used as defaults for Japanese?

Comment: Does the application itself have a language setting, independent of the OS?  Is that what you're trying to achieve?   Or do you literally need to display Japanese text next to English text in the same running app?   In the former case, you would have all of your language strings in a .RESX file, one version of this file per language.  At application start, you would get a CultureInfo for the current language setting and set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` to it.  Then your strings would come out in the right language

Comment: In other words, the problem is not a font problem, it's a culture/language-translation problem

Comment: In this case, the app is overriding the various thread culture settings. When Windows sees use of Japanese characters in a font that doesn't support it it will actually find a suitable Japanese font and swap it in just for those characters. So, for example, you'll see Times New Roman latin characters and then Meiryo for Japanese characters. However, if you don't have a Japanese font then you'll get the dreaded empty boxes and that's what I'm trying to detect.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Is your  application a WIndows-only app or cross platform?  If it is a Windows-only app does it use WPF, by any chance?

Comment: I ask because if it is Windows-only and uses WPF you could use `System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies` to enumerate what is available.  Each `FontFamily` object has a `FamilyMaps` collection and each FontFamilyMap object in that collection has a `Language` property which should allow you to determine if any fonts are targeted towards Japanese